# What is the passphrase-file in apache2?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I'm referring to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart?s=275b3be7-5cca-45ea-82c9-99f99cbb6901) question. What is the 'passphrase-file' mentioned in here? Please clarify.

Comment: That would be wherever you save the script also noted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer, `/path/to/passphrase-file` is given as an **example path and filename** to wherever you decide to put the helper script.

Answer (score 0):

It contains the passphrase to the private key. For apache to use the certificate, it needs a key to unlock it when apache gets started at boot time, but there is no user interaction so the best choice is to use a passphrase-file. It enters the password for you when apache requests it to enter it. Sometimes the key file doesn't have a password (not recommended) it still might ask for a password. so you will still need one that outputs no text but just like pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the `passphrase-file` is a *shell script*. You're configuring apache to invoke a shell script when it needs the password instead of prompting on the interactive terminal (`SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:` means "execute the following program and expect it to return the SSL password"). The example shell script just `echo`s the password back to apache. You can use any script which returns the password in its place, if you wanted to set up more complex authentication.